# is .maintenance file still valid for putting WP in maintenance mode?

Tags: maintenance

I see that upon upgrades the .maintenance file is deleted, if present. Is it still a viable/correct way to put WP in maintenance mode?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not really.

`.maintenance` is a temporary file, not viable if you want to put your site in maintenance mode for a long time.

If you look at [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/load.php#L162-L165) the maintenance mode is maintained only if `$upgrading` variable defined in the file is no older than 10 minutes.

It means `.maintenance` is a sort of *lock file* when WordPress is upgrading plugins, themes or itself, something that should not last more than 10 minutes.

Surely is possible to insert into that file something like:

```
$upgrading = time();
```

And in theory hold WordPress in maintenance mode, but once it is intended to be a temporary file, WordPress feels free to delete the file after a successfull update.

For a long-duration maintenance mode you need to use a different solution.

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169610/35541) you'll find one.

Answer (score 27):

Step 1: Create a file `.maintenance` in the WP root directory like `.htaccess`

Step 2: Put this code in the file

```
<?php $upgrading = time(); ?>
```

Step 3: Save the file. Then you can see the default maintenance message 'Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.'.

Step 4: Once you have finished the repair or upgrade, then delete the code or the file `.maintenance`.

In case you want to have your own custom warning message, create a `maintenance.php` file and placing it in your `/wp-content/` directory. WordPress uses this file to display during any forced maintenance period that you might have.